# Error while batch insert data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 100,000 records and have to perform batch insert in `codeigniter`. But getting the following error. Can any one provide me a solution?

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   ''scheduleId','userId','userType','active','createdBy','createdOn','updatedBy')
>   (' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO scheduled_user_details('scheduleId','userId','userType','active','createdBy','createdOn','updatedBy') () 
VALUES ('600','401','lead','1','81114','2016-01-19 13:01:55','81114'), ('600','402','lead','1','81114','2016-01-19 13:01:55','81114')
```

Comment: $str="scheduled_user_details('scheduleId','userId','userType','active','createdBy','createdOn','updatedBy')";
        $ress = $this->_ci->db->insert_batch($str,$data);

Comment: The above query is providing an error

Comment: Why you are having "()" before VALUES ?

Comment: Do not use single quotes around column names. Use backticks to escape them.

Comment: @Aravind i an not having () before values but the the codeigniter is adding automatically when i  execute the query                                                                
$str="scheduled_user_details('scheduleId','userId','userType','active','createdB‌​y','createdOn','updatedBy')"; $ress = $this->_ci->db->insert_batch($str,$data);

Answer (score 1):

> Error near
>   ''scheduleId','userId','userType','active','createdBy','createdOn','updatedBy')

Its very clear you are using empty `()` in your query. You need to remove this bracket **()**

**Second**, remove quotes from columns name and use backticks.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

As per your comments, you are using CodeIgniter Framework. you can not use batch query as like your example:

[FROM the CodeIgniter User Guide:](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

You can use batch insert query as like that:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'scheduleId' => '600' ,
      'userId' => '401' ,
      'userType' => 'lead',
      'active' => '1',
      'createdBy' => '81114',
      'createdOn' => '2016-01-19 13:01:55',
      'updatedBy' => '81114'
   ),
   array(
      'scheduleId' => '600' ,
      'userId' => '402' ,
      'userType' => 'lead',
      'active' => '1',
      'createdBy' => '81114',
      'createdOn' => '2016-01-19 13:01:55',
      'updatedBy' => '81114'
   )
);

$this->_ci->db->insert_batch('scheduled_user_details', $data);
```

Comment: @Jens: yes my friend, i have updated... ist intention to provide the reason of the error.

Comment: $str="scheduled_user_details('scheduleId','userId','userType','active','createdBy','createdOn','updatedBy')";
        $ress = $this->_ci->db->insert_batch($str,$data);

Comment: the above query is returning the () before values

Comment: @devpro   $str="scheduled_user_details('scheduleId','userId','userType','active','createdB‌​y','createdOn','updatedBy')"; $ress = $this->_ci->db->insert_batch($str,$data); – ramu 23 secs ago   edit   
     
the above query is returning the  () before values

Comment: @devpro the problem is the () braces is inserted automaticallty is there any way to remove it

Comment: @Pallavi: r u using codignitor? batch_insert?

Comment: if you are using Codignitor batch insert than this is the wrong way.. @Pallavi

Comment: yesi am using codeignitor. Please lemme know the right way to insert.$data is an array with huge data and i dont want to insert 1 record at  atime

Comment: @Pallavi: follow this and check how can u use batch_insert in CI https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: i had checked this to write the query

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
INSERT INTO scheduled_user_details('scheduleId','userId','userType','active','createdBy','createdOn','updatedBy') () 
VALUES ('600','401','lead','1','81114','2016-01-19 13:01:55','81114'), ('600','402','lead','1','81114','2016-01-19 13:01:55','81114')
```

to this

```
INSERT INTO scheduled_user_details(scheduleId,userId,userType,active,createdBy,createdOn,updatedBy)
VALUES ('600','401','lead','1','81114','2016-01-19 13:01:55','81114'), 
       ('600','402','lead','1','81114','2016-01-19 13:01:55','81114')
```

> Removed  `()` near values field

When you insert batch of data use ***[`INSERT IGNORE INTO`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm)***